# Any ideas why is this join query performing table scan and if there's a way I can eliminate it?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, query-optimization

On the following two table structure:

### `posts` table:

```
   Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers                      
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 body       | character varying(1000)     | 
 person_id  | integer                     | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 slug       | character varying(255)      |
```

Indexes:

```
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_on_slug" UNIQUE, btree (slug)
    "index_on_body" btree (body)
    "index_on_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "index_on_updated_at" btree (updated_at)
```

### `posts_topics` table:

```
  Column  |  Type   |                         Modifiers                          
----------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer | not null default nextval('posts_topics_id_seq'::regclass)
 quote_id | integer | 
 topic_id | integer |
```

Indexes:

```
    "posts_topics_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_posts_topics_on_topic_id_and_quote_id" UNIQUE, btree (topic_id, quote_id)
    "index_posts_topics_on_quote_id" btree (quote_id)
    "index_posts_topics_on_topic_id" btree (topic_id)
```

The following query:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "posts_topics" ON "posts"."id" = "posts_topics"."quote_id" 
WHERE "posts_topics"."topic_id" = 297 
ORDER BY "posts"."updated_at" ASC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 16340;
```

Leads to the following query plan:

```
 Limit  (cost=65299.69..65299.72 rows=10 width=219) (actual time=768.913..768.914 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=65258.84..65301.95 rows=17243 width=219) (actual time=762.651..768.167 rows=16350 loops=1)
         Sort Key: posts.updated_at
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4664kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=30177.21..62214.98 rows=17243 width=219) (actual time=290.098..738.999 rows=17589 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (posts_topics.quote_id = posts.id)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on posts_topics  (cost=326.06..21967.63 rows=17243 width=4) (actual time=4.343..22.194 rows=17589 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (topic_id = 297)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_posts_topics_on_topic_id  (cost=0.00..321.75 rows=17243 width=0) (actual time=2.400..2.400 rows=17589 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (topic_id = 297)
               ->  Hash  (cost=15750.51..15750.51 rows=329651 width=219) (actual time=280.392..280.392 rows=329651 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 679kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..15750.51 rows=329651 width=219) (actual time=0.003..95.573 rows=329651 loops=1)
```

[View this plan on http://explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/qLh).

As it can be seen the Hash Join leads to a Seq Scan on posts that has 329651 rows and overall the Hash Join part of query takes about `738ms`.

As both of `post_topcics.id` and `posts.id` are indexed, I don't understand why a Seq Scan is being performed on `posts`. Any ideas why?

Also is there a way I can eliminate it?

### Update 1

As suggested by @IgorRomanchenko and @a_horse_with_no_name I increased the `work_mem` to `128MB`, and it improved the query run time from the original `~780ms` down to `~260ms`.

Comment: If full table seqscans were always bad, PostgreSQL wouldn't implement them, or would issue a warning when using them. Sometimes they are the fastest way. So don't assume a seqscan is always bad. Your question in this case is really "how do I make my query faster"; anything else is flailing and guesswork at this point.

Comment: As you are also requesting all columns of the posts table, the seq scan is most probably faster than doing an index scan and then 17589 lookups to retrieve the columns. For testing purposes, what happens when you don't select `posts.*` but `posts.id`. This would enable the optimizer to use an index only scan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name An index scan looks up each heap tuple anyway, because it must get the `xmin` and `xmax`. Only index-only scans in 9.2 and above can avoid this - and you're right that reducing the columns selected would permit an index-*only* scan in 9.2.

Comment: BTW, sample data is quite handy for this sort of post. Makes it more practical to test variations.

Comment: `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4664kB` means that `work_mem` is set wery low. Consider increasing `work_mem`

Comment: The topic_id and quote_id in the posts_topics table could probably made NOT NULL, and both FK's. In that case you could also omit the id (surrogate) PK, which is not needed in a junction table; and make {topic_id, quote_id} the PK, and add an unique index on {quote_id,topic_id}.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: increasing `work_mem` helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Stats

Your statistics estimates look bang on, so it doesn't look like bad table stats or bad statistics estimation. See [your plan on explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/qLh) - note that there aren't big mismatches between actual and estimated rows.

### Cost parameters

With questions like this, it often turns out that Pg thinks your random I/O is more expensive than it really is, so it's preferring a scan and hash join to an index scan.

Try significantly lowering `random_page_cost`. Also make sure `effective_cache_size` reflects your system accurately.

See:

- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions
- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server
- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

### Version

Are you on Pg 9.2 or newer? If not, upgrade. There are plenty of performance improvements. For just one example, index-only scans could be quite useful for a query like this.

### Range queries should avoid `OFFSET` where possible

This is exceedingly bad for performance:

> LIMIT 10 OFFSET 16340;

Huge limit/offset queries can easily perform quite miserably. PostgreSQL must generate, and discard, all the prior 16340 rows.

If at all possible re-phrase the query to use a filter range. In this case you're doing `ORDER BY "posts"."updated_at" ASC`, so you should be able to write something like:

```
WHERE "posts_topics"."topic_id" = 297 
  AND posts.updated_at > ?
```

and pass the greatest `updated_at` from the last set of rows you retrieved as the input.

### Force multiple passes

If you're on 9.2 with index-only scans, it's possible that you may be able to benefit from a two-pass approach: Determine which post IDs are of interest, then do another scan to get the rest of the post info for those IDs. That way you aren't generating and throwing away the other ten thousand.

```
SELECT p2.*
FROM (
  SELECT posts.id
  FROM posts
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM posts_topics pt
    WHERE pt.quote_id = posts.id 
    AND pt.topic_id = 297
  )
  ORDER BY "posts"."updated_at" ASC 
  LIMIT 10 
  OFFSET 16340
) wanted_posts
INNER JOIN posts p2 ON wanted_posts.id = p2.id;
```

This almost certainly won't do any good unless you're able to use an index-only scan on `post_topics` and/or `posts`. Otherwise you're paying most of the cost of the heap lookups for each discarded row anyway.

I'm a bit dubious about whether that'll be possible because of the need to join, *then* sort and discard. A composite index on `posts_topics(topic_id, quote_id)` and on `posts(id, updated_at)` (or opposite ordering) *might* prove useful, but I'm not sure and don't have the time to delve in with test cases or poking at the guts of the query planner code at present.

Comment: All this is very informative, but in OP's case, the plan is the best he can possibly get. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I played with limit/offset a bit and even when the offset is 0 the query takes almost the same amount of time. Also that limit/offset is generated by a pagination library I am using in my Ruby on Rails app so at the moment I can not tweak that.

Answer (score 2):

As I read your plan and the stats, it is the best plan you can possibly get...

The issue with your query is the huge offset, which basically amounts to fetching 10 of the last rows yielded by the query without the limit/offset. What more, Postgres anticipates precisely this with its row estimates.

Think of such a query as fetching the top 16350 rows of a set, and eliminating them all except the last 10. This is way beyond "use an index" territory in your case since it basically amounts to fetching the entire set (and a significant part of the table, to boot): if you do an index scan for that with your cardinality, you'll basically do random accesses to the disk across the plan (and de facto, the entire table), and that'll be even slower; better grab the whole thing sequentially, sort in memory, and begone with it.

You *might* achieve an index-only scan in recent Postgres versions (provided all columns involved are in indexes), but it wouldn't be significantly faster: you'd still end up reading and hash joining the entire index anyway...

Edit: as point out by @a_horse_with_no_name, that being said, there is some writing to disk involved that you could avoid by increasng the work mem. Increasing it might make the hash joining and sorting in your plan materially faster.

Comment: I wonder if the hashing of the rows from the `posts` table can be improved by increasing work_mem for that statement. The line `Buckets: 1024  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 679kB` indicates the hashing is done on disk if I'm not mistaken. So the 175ms it takes could be improved. That _might_ also improve the sorting that is done on disk.

Comment: @Denis, thanks for the answer. I played with limit/offset a bit, and even when the offset is set to 0, the query is still slow (that is before tweaking `work_mem`). When offset is `16340`, the query takes `882ms`. When it is `0`, the query takes `763ms`.

Comment: @drop-shadow: ok, now you have me *really* wanting to run my own tests on your data. Not that I don't believe you, but hey, I'm willing to report performance bugs to Tom Lane on pg-bugs. You *are* running the latest and greatest Postgres, correct?

Comment: Btw, if this is a prepared plan rather than a parametrized query, your 760ms vs 880ms plan actually makes sense. In essence, the prepared plan prepares for the worst, which is a huge offset, so you'd get the same plan (give or take `top n` in sql server parlance).

Comment: @Denis: I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.2 with default settings.

Comment: @Denis also I am not sure if this is a prepared plan or not. Is it the same thing as `PreparedStatement` in JDBC? This particular app is using Ruby on Rails/ActiveRecord using the `pg` gem, but I am not sure if it is creating prepared statements or not. Having said that in the query I see $1, $2 placeholders for parameters I am passing to the query.

Comment: @Denis, also in my tests, and the query plans I posted, I just use psql, replace the $n arguments with valid values, and execute the query there. So actually the framework (RoR) is not involved at all.

Comment: Looks like increasing the work mem did the trick. I think you'll get barely better than that, but dopist the updated plan.